# How to insert and update the query in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

Hi I am trying to insert and update the query in function using Angularjs and returning the data in the form of JSON objects. In this query I am comparing year and email. If there is no data for current year and email the data should be inserted otherwise the data should be updated. But when I am trying that the data is not inserting when I write both conditions (Insert and Update). If I write only insert query it is accepting.

```
function addrentalproperty($data)
{
    $rentalannualrent = $data->rentalProperty->rentalannualrent;
    $rentalblock = $data->rentalProperty->rentalblock;
    $rentalstreet = $data->rentalProperty->rentalstreet;
    $rentalarea = $data->rentalProperty->rentalarea;
    $rentaltown = $data->rentalProperty->rentalcity;
    $rentalstate = $data->rentalProperty->rentalstate;
    $rentalpincode = $data->rentalProperty->rentalpincode;

    session_start();
    $userInfo = $_SESSION['USER'];
    $userEmailid = $userInfo->getEmailid();
    if ($rentalannualrent != '' && $rentalblock != '' && $rentalstreet != '' && $rentalarea != '' && $rentaltown != '' && $rentalstate != '' && $rentalpincode != '') {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE rental_details SET
rental_annual_rent         = '$rentalannualrent',
rental_block               = '$rentalblock',
rental_street              = '$rentalstreet',
rental_area                = '$rentalarea',
rental_town                = '$rentaltown',
rental_state               = '$rentalstate',
rental_pincode             = '$rentalpincode',
WHERE email ='$userEmailid' AND currentyear=NOW()");
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rental_details(email,rental_annual_rent,rental_block,rental_street,rental_area,rental_town,rental_state,rental_pincode,rental_ownership,currentyear)
values('$userEmailid','$rentalannualrent','$rentalblock','$rentalstreet','$rentalarea','$rentaltown','$rentalstate','$rentalpincode','$rentalownership',NOW())");
    }
    if ($query) {
        $successJson = '{"success":"Rental Property Details Added Successfully."}';
        print_r($successJson);
    } else {
        $failureJson = '{"error":"Problem While Saving Property Details."}';
        print_r($successJson);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `print_r` to output back to the JS, use `json_encode($successJson);`

Comment: The problem is it is not inserting the data into if i write both conditions then .it is accepting only one condition.But i need to write both conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, `NOW()` will provide the current date and time and it will not provide the year.

But you are using `NOW()` to check against current year in your update query.

This could be an issue if you insert year and trying to update by checking current time.

Another thing is, if you insert current time in the current year field, then your update query will never work.

You should use `YEAR(CURDATE())` to get the current year.

Use the below query and check.

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE rental_details SET
                         rental_annual_rent         = '$rentalannualrent',
                         rental_block               = '$rentalblock',
                         rental_street              = '$rentalstreet',
                         rental_area                = '$rentalarea',
                         rental_town                = '$rentaltown',
                         rental_state               = '$rentalstate',
                         rental_pincode             = '$rentalpincode',
                         WHERE email ='$userEmailid' AND currentyear=YEAR(CURDATE())");
```

**EDIT 1 :**

It will not insert. Because of the below condition,

```
if($rentalannualrent!='' &&$rentalblock!='' &&$rentalstreet!='' &&$rentalarea!='' &&$rentaltown!='' &&$rentalstate!='' &&$rentalpincode!='')
{
```

All these values are required by the insert query. Obviously, all the variables should be well set and it should have some values.

If all these variables have any data, it will always go to UPDATE part. Your INSERT query will never be executed.

Ideally no data in database. so, UPDATE also will not work.

So, check your condition and change the logic.

**EDIT 2 :**

```
$userEmailid= $userInfo-> getEmailid();

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rental_details WHERE email ='$userEmailid' AND currentyear=YEAR(CURDATE())";
$records = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($records > 0) { 
   // UPDATE query
} else {
  // INSERT query
}
```

PS: Do not use Mysql_*. It is deprecated. Please switch to mysqli_* (or) PDO.

Comment: No it is not working there is no data in my table then it should insert but also it is not inserting

Comment: @user6006309 Edited the answer. Check that

Comment: Actually my condition is if there is no data for current year and email then the data should be inserted,if there is data for that email and date the data should be updated

Comment: In if conditions iam checking if that fields are not empty it should be updated and in else condition it is inserting if there is no data

Comment: Then how can i check both the conditions can you tell me

Comment: @user6006309 What are the conditions? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: my condition is if there is any data for current year and email that data should be updated else it should be inserted.

Comment: @user6006309 Write a SELECT query before the condition and your where condition should be exactly what you have in UPDATE query. If that query returns any data, then run UPDATE or else run INSERT query. Then, remove the current if condition which never work. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: why to write select query and where i need to add that

Comment: i have tried but it is inserting it is not updating the record